# active record object, handle nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class as below

```
class UserPerformance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and I'm using `object.user_performance.something` in my views and specs, but if `user_performance` is nil it will throw an error. What is the correct way to handle that?

I cannot do in specs: `... to eq(something: object.user_performance.something if object.user_performance)` etc and I wish to get nil everytime I do `object.user_performance.something` when `user_performance` is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try` method

```
object.user_performance.try(:something)
```

if user_performance will be nil it will return nil :)

You can also handle this:

```
if object.user_performance.nil?
   #ups error what next?
else
   object.user_performance.something
end
```

Comment: In Ruby 2.3 you can use the safe navigation operator instead: `object.user_performance&.something`.